# PHP MySQL 24h Query outputs 24h +10h

Tags: php, sql, time, timezone

I am running the following SQL Query in a php script:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(LogDateTime, '%k:%i') AS LogDate, Temp AS OutsideTemp, InsideTemp 
FROM cumuluslog.monthly 
WHERE LogDateTime > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
ORDER BY LogDateTime
```

The problem is, instead of getting the past 24 hours, I get about 34 hours, I have checked that my timezone is set to +10 (My Local timezone). When running the same query directly from phpmyadmin, it gives me the correct result.

I have tried setting the timezone in the .php scriot using: `date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Brisbane );`

It seems like it is running the query for the last day, then adding the +10 h timezone after. I have searched around but cant seem to find anyone with the same issue.

Comment: check the mysql timezones with `SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;`

Comment: It comes up with @@global.time_zone SYSTEM, @@session.time_zone SYSTEM.

Comment: Thank you Dagon, this led me on the right path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your MySQL server has the wrong timezone set. You can either set the system time correctly and restart MySQL, or tell it what zone to use at runtime:

```
mysql_query("SET time_zone = 'Australia/Brisbane'");
mysql_query("YOUR QUERY HERE");
```

Comment: I did try and set the timezone using the SET time_zone command, but I didn't not realize you have yo do it per query or session. Since there are multiple uses using the database, it might be an idea to set the system timezone correctly and restart. as this is an XAMPP Server running on Windows for the moment, would it just be the PC Time Zone settings? or is there a conf file I need to edit?

Comment: You can set this in the my.cnf file: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//time-zone-support.html

Comment: Edit: This did fix the issue, it turns out I was doing something stupid in the code. Its all working now, Thank you Cal!